# Cannot play sound with AVAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, swift

I am trying to play an audio file using the AVAudioEngine. I have seen several examples, and I'm just following the same steps. However, the sound is not being played. Here's my code:

```
var audioUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "my-path-to-audio-file")
var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()

audioEngine.attachNode(myPlayer)

var audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioUrl, error: nil)
var audioError: NSError?

audioEngine.connect(myPlayer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

myPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&audioError)

myPlayer.play()
```

The reason I am not simply using AVAudioPlayer is because I need to add later some effects.

Can anyone please help me out with that?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging `audioError`?

Comment: Yes.. And i got "nil" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code, and it worked fine, there are three things I would check:

1. Make sure your file is found, so change your code to work with AVAudioPlayer just to check that the program knows where the file is, and that it can play it
2. Second, check where you are putting your statements, my example with the code is below.

   ```
   import UIKit
   import AVFoundation
   class aboutViewController: UIViewController {

       var audioUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("chimes", ofType: "wav")!)
       var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
       var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

           audioEngine.attachNode(myPlayer)
           var audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioUrl, error: nil)
           var audioError: NSError?
           audioEngine.connect(myPlayer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)
           myPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
           audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&audioError)


       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }

       @IBAction func testSound(sender: AnyObject) {
           myPlayer.play()
       }
   ```

   }

Hope this helps, ask if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I have just updated xcode and my code worked.. It seems that it was a bug.